# Silverlight binding to page inside item template

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I have strange problem with bindings.
Check this gist please
  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/865b0848f61cfdf988a5

As you can see i have the sane code at lines
17-28
and 53-69.

First one works like a charm when second one doesn't work at all ( it shows like 1pixel height red line ).

What is the defference ? Why it works in first place and doesn't work at second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the second one is that it's inside the GridView's ItemTemplate, and therefore it's no longer in the same [namescope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx) as "Page".  You should be able to get around this by using a [`RelativeSource / FindAncestor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx) binding instead:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=extras:ExtendedPage,Path=RolesViewModel}"
```